# How to use variable from a method in another method C++

Tags: c++, variables, methods, compare

I want to use a variable in another method.
I have a method that return the current date(today_date()) and a method that parse the file of the current date.

So what I want to do is to compare the date and the filename bellow the comment "//Compare ". but I don't know how to use the variable "date" in the other method

This is my code with comments.

```
//***Start today_date method**
 void parsing::today_date() {
    std::time_t t = std::time(0);   // get time now
    std::tm* now = std::localtime(&t);
    int year= (now->tm_year + 1900);
    string syear(to_string(year));
    int month = (now->tm_mon + 1);
    string smonth(to_string(month));
    int day = now->tm_mday;
    string sday(to_string(day));
    if(smonth.length()== 1){
        smonth = '0' + smonth;
    }
    if(sday.length()== 1){
        sday = '0' + sday;
    }
    string datee= syear + smonth+ sday + ".jrn" ;
   cout << datee << endl; // This is the variable that I want to use in the second method
}
    //end of method
```

The second method

```
//***Start parsing function*****
void parsing::parse(const char* path){
    string str_path = string(path);
    //find filename

  unsigned found = str_path.find_last_of("/\\");
  string same_path = str_path.substr(found+1);
  cout << "this is the file name" << endl;
  cout <<same_path << endl;

  //Compare
    if (datee.today_date()== same_path){ // error datee was not declared in this scope
        cout << "Both the input strings are equal." << endl;
        ifstream file1(path);
    string str;
    if(file1.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(file1, str))
        {
            cout << str << "\n";
        }
        file1.close();
    }
    else
        cout <<"File not found " << endl;

    file1.close();}

        else
            cout << "Both the input strings are different." <<endl;
}
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: You could change the return type of `today_date` to `std::string` and return `datee`.

Comment: It's a (non-static) local variable of the function – so it ceases to exist as soon as it runs out of scope on leaving the function. Generally you now have to ways to make it available to other functions: 1. The latter might be called directly from within the first function and the value is passed on as parameter. 2. You *return* the value in question (by value, not reference or pointer!), store it in a variable one level up the call stack and then pass it on as such to the next function (or directly, the function call being placed directly as function argument of the next function).

Comment: The specific case rather speaks for the second approach, as parsing is not a (logical) sub-task (i.e. part of the algorithm) of/essential to getting today's date.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the return type of `today_date` to `std::string` and return `datee` and use that return value for the comparison with `same_path` as shown below. Note i have removed some code just so that the example just shows the part that i have changed and is more readable/clear.

```
vvvvvvvvvvv---------------------------> return type changed
std::string parsing::today_date() {
    
    //other code here as before

    string datee= syear + smonth+ sday + ".jrn" ;
    return datee; //return datee

}
void parsing::parse(const char* path){
    string str_path = string(path);
    //find filename

  unsigned found = str_path.find_last_of("/\\");
  string same_path = str_path.substr(found+1);
 

//------vvvvvvvvvvv------------->call today_date which will return datee by value
    if (today_date()== same_path){ 
//------^^^^^^^^^^^^----------->equivalent to writing this->today_date()
}
  
//other code here as before

}
```

The changes that i made include:

1. changed the return type of `today_date` to `std::string` inside method `today_date`.
2. Called `today_date` to compare the call result with `same_path` inside method `parse`.